# Implementing auto complete in Java - am I doing it right?

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, jframe, jwindow

### Algorithm

1. Start
2. Input a city name - partial or complete
3. If the user hits enter , take the text from `JTextField`
4. Begin brute force search.
5. If the matches are found, put them in a `Vector` and put it in a `JList`
6. If no match is found, add a `String` "No Match Found" in `Vector`
7. Display `JWindow` to user containing the results
8. Stop

### Code:

```
package test;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Vector;

public class AutoCompleteTest extends JFrame{
    JTextField city = new JTextField(10);
    String enteredName = null;
    String[] cities = {"new jersey","new hampshire",
            "sussex","essex","london","delhi","new york"};
    JList list = new JList();
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane();
    ResultWindow r = new ResultWindow();
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AutoCompleteTest();
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public AutoCompleteTest(){
        setLayout(new java.awt.FlowLayout());
        setVisible(true);
        add(city);
//      add(pane);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        city.addKeyListener(new TextHandler());
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void initiateSearch(String lookFor){
        Vector<String> matches = new Vector<>();
        lookFor = lookFor.toLowerCase();
        for(String each : cities){
            if(each.contains(lookFor)){
                matches.add(each);
                System.out.println("Match: " + each);
            }
        }
        this.repaint();

        if(matches.size()!=0){
            list.setListData(matches);
            r.searchResult = list;
            r.pane = pane;
            r.initiateDisplay();
        }else{
            matches.add("No Match Found");
            list.setListData(matches);
            r.searchResult = list;
            r.pane = pane;
            r.initiateDisplay();
        }

    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public class ResultWindow extends JWindow{
        public JScrollPane pane;
        public JList searchResult;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public ResultWindow(){

        }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public void initiateDisplay(){
            pane.setViewportView(searchResult);
            add(pane);
            pack();
            this.setLocation(AutoCompleteTest.this.getX() + 2, 
                    AutoCompleteTest.this.getY()+
                    AutoCompleteTest.this.getHeight());

//          this.setPreferredSize(city.getPreferredSize());
            this.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    class TextHandler implements KeyListener{
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            if(r.isVisible()){
                r.setVisible(false);
            }
            if(e.getKeyChar() == '\n'){
                initiateSearch(city.getText());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){

        }
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

### Output

[image]

### Problem

The size of the `JWindow` displaying the results (which is a `JList` in a `JScrollPane`) changes based on the results - if the city name is small, `JWindow` is small, if the city name is big, `JWindow` is big.

I have tried every possible combination. I tried using `setPreferredDimension()` of the `JWindow`, the `JList` and `JScrollPane` but the issue won't go.
I want it to match the size of the decorated `JFrame` no matter what

Comment: Why don't you add the autocomplete gui below the textfield in the same jframe?

Comment: Besides the mentioned problem, your gui has another problem, the autocomplete window does not move with the textfield's frame. This thread[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427815/java-how-to-register-a-listener-that-listen-to-a-jframe-movement] solves this problem.

Comment: it does move. The `setLocation()` is relative to the decorated `JFrame`

Comment: If already visible, autocomplete list does not move with the JFrame. It appears at correct location when pressed enter though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `JList` or `JComboBox` doesn't returns proper `PreferredSize`, have to set this value, use [JList.setPrototypeCellValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setPrototypeCellValue%28E%29) with `pack()` for `JWindow` (must be packed after any changes) and or with [JList.setVisibleRowCount()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setVisibleRowCount%28int%29), then value returns `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()` for `JList` in `JScrollPane`
- don't to use [`KeyListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html), use [`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) (chars can be inserted from system clipboard) for [`JTextComponents`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html)
- don't to reinvent the wheel, use [AutoComplete JComboBox / JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7255918/714968), you can to redirect / returns result from matches to the popup [`JWindow` / undecorated `JDialog`(quite the best workaround for popup recycle)](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/)

EDIT

> Anyways so basically I will have to manually create a list of all the
>   cities that are to be supported right ?? bx @Little Child

- this idea could be quite easy, you can to put [`JTable` to the `JWindow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)
- with one `Column`,
- without `JTableHeader`
- add there [RowSorter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) (see code example in tutorial)
- then every steps are done :-), nothing else is required there (maybe bonus to change `Background` of `JTextField` in the case that `RowFilter` returns no matches, add `setVisible` for popup window from `DocumentListener` (be sure to test for `!isVisible`))

Comment: This one is better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673807/implementing-java2sautotextfield-to-a-jtextfield. Anyways so basically I will have to manually create a list of all the cities that are to be supported right ??

Comment: This one is better == the same code, I'll edit my answer here

Comment: +1 For being a Swing geek :)

Comment: @mKorbel I was going over the `AutoCompleteTextField` by Java 2s and I was wondering if I could download their API as a jar or zip. Is that possible ?

Comment: there are only two classes, (copy ---> paste, nothing else required) one for JTextField, 2nd for JComboBox, you needed both :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the width of the the `JFrame` every time you initiate the search and use it calculate the width of the list.

Just change the initiateSearch() function like this:

```
public void initiateSearch(String lookFor){

    //add the following two statements to set the width of the list.
    int newWidth = AutoCompleteTest.this.getSize().width;        
    list.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(newWidth, list.getPreferredSize().height));

        Vector<String> matches = new Vector<String>();
        lookFor = lookFor.toLowerCase();
        for(String each : cities){
            if(each.contains(lookFor)){
                matches.add(each);
                System.out.println("Match: " + each);
            }
        }
        this.repaint();

        if(matches.size()!=0){
            list.setListData(matches);
            r.searchResult = list;
            r.pane = pane;
            r.initiateDisplay();
        }else{
            matches.add("No Match Found");
            list.setListData(matches);
            r.searchResult = list;
            r.pane = pane;
            r.initiateDisplay();
        }

    }
```

Here is a sample output:

[image: small size]

and

[image]

PS: Just for better aesthetics try using some layout to make the text field fill the entire width.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [JComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html), and for the autocompletion, read [this article](http://www.orbital-computer.de/JComboBox/).

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to change initiateDisplay() to this:

```
public void initiateDisplay()
    {
        this.pane.setViewportView(this.searchResult);
        this.add(this.pane);
        this.pack();
        this.setLocation(AutoCompleteTest.this.getX() + 2, AutoCompleteTest.this.getY()
                + AutoCompleteTest.this.getHeight());

        int padding = 5;
        int height = this.searchResult.getModel().getSize()
                * AutoCompleteTest.this.city.getSize().height;
        int windowWidth = AutoCompleteTest.this.getSize().width;

        this.setSize(windowWidth, height);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
```